# Visual Basic .NET VS 2017 Build Directives - build tab missing. VS Custom Constraints

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Basic Visual Studio 2017 I can not find the build directives. The build tab is missing.

Example directive

```
#If Not STEAMCLIENT Then
    'code here
#End If
```

Docs from Microsoft: Here is the Microsoft docs on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/if-then-else-directives

I tried to set it in the advanced compiler settings based on this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/define but I could not find the setting:
[image]

Settings from the project:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks right I think.  A Build Tab shows up in a c# project, not in a VB.Net project in my studio.

Comment: Where do you add the directives?

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Q` for **Quick Launch**, type `Build` and see if there's any option available.

Comment: Explain what you're actually trying to achieve, not how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: I am trying to add language directives to control what code goes into different builds of our StudyX software. Here is the Microsoft docs on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/if-then-else-directives but I did not see how to add them to the compiler yet.

Comment: If you're looking for Build events (pre-build, post-build), there's a button in the Compile panel. Otherwise, add those in code files.

Comment: I updated the description ad added more pictures. Let me know if that helps. I am trying to do #if

Comment: Are you saying something is preventing you from writing that code?  Use the @ sign in front of a user name to reply to that person.

Comment: If all you want to do is set custom build constants, go to "Advanced Compile Options..." at the bottom of the "Compile" ply.  (C# exposes it directly on the "Build" ply.)  Just enter it into the "Custom constants" box---anything you name there will get defined (I think as 1 if no value is provided by you).  That's also where you go to set or clear the DEBUG or TRACE constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. They can be defined as Custom constants (below the define debug and define trace options). Example: `Win32=True`
[image]